# What characters need to be escaped or replaced to prevent xss jsonp callback attacks?

Tags: javascript, jsonp, xss

Previously [asked here.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192309/what-characters-need-to-be-escaped-or-replaced-to-prevent-xss-jsonp-callback-att) Asking again on SO to try getting a better set of responses.

I have a service which allows the user to specify a callback function name that wraps the data being returned to support jsonp callbacks. I want to make sure that I am covering all of my bases in regards to preventing XSS attacks.

Note, I have read through the [OWASP security checklist](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192309/what-characters-need-to-be-escaped-or-replaced-to-prevent-xss-jsonp-callback-att) but none of the recommendations seem to directly address this question.

These are the currently supported methods for specifying the jsonp function where the function name is `cbFn` and `cbFn` is declared on its own, a method on an object, or being accessed from an object/array:

```
https://service.com/cbFn
https://service.com/?callback=cbFn
https://service.com/?callback=obj.cbFn
https://service.com/?callback=obj['cbFn']
https://service.com/?callback=obj[1]
```

These return:

```
cbFn({data: 'data being returned'})
obj.cbFn({data: 'data being returned'})
obj['cbFn']({data: 'data being returned'})
obj[1]({data: 'data being returned'})
```

However the following requests *also* work and are the known XSS issues I want to circumvent:

```
// executes an anonymous function
https://service.com/?callback=(()=%3E{alert(1)})
// replaces the user's callback function with our own
https://service.com/?callback=cbFn=((data)=>{alert(data)})
```

Is it enough to just replace/remove the characters `()=>` in the callback name to prevent XSS vulnerabilities? I want to allow the full valid javascript character set for function names, so restricting the valid character range to `/[$_\w]+/` (alphanumeric plus $ and _) doesn't seem to be a good option.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names) is literally the (long) whitelist regex. And well, I would definitly go with a whitelist not a blacklist. You never know about future features! Also: don't use jsonp at all! And *if* you do so then stay with alphanumeric characters. But really dont use jsonp. Do you *really* have to support IE7? (the only reason to use JSONP)

Comment: Thanks @Lux. I ran across that regex too. The service already supports CORS but a surprisingly large amount of users still access it via jsonp (mainly jquery users). I have a rather large user base already, so when I discovered this the other day it immediately raised many red flags. I’m thinking after researching today it will be better just to filter out characters like (){}=><+- and their escapes forms. That should get the job done and not have a huge impact on existing users.

Comment: you could monitor what people actually use and build a good whitelist. But using cors almost always means autogenerating the function name, so `/[$_\w]+/` should be good.